# Attributing inputs to a list to form a table

Tags: python

I am trying to make two lists with the inputs provided, that are then displayed, and organized in a table. So far, I get an error because of NivGlicemia being an undefined name. Am stuck in this part and have tried to look for solutions, unsuccessfully.

```
semana = ("Segunda Feira", "Terça Feira", "Quarta Feira", "Quinta Feira", 
"Sexta", "Sabado", "Domingo")

var = 0

glicemia = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

NivGlicemia = ()

while var < 7:
    print ("Niveis de glicemia de", semana[var])
    glicemia = input()
    NivGlicemia.append(glicemia) #Error here
    var = var + 1

while True:
    try:
        glicemia = float(glicemia)
        if glicemia == 0:
            glicemia = input("Introduza um valor diferente de 0. ")
        else:
            break
except ValueError:
    glicemia = input("Nao inseriu um valor adequado, qual é o nivel de glicemia? ")

print (NivGlicemia)

var = 0

batimentos = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

BatCard = ()

while var < 7:
    print ("Batimento cardiaco medio de", semana[var])
    batimentos = input()
    BatCard.append(batimentos)
    var = var + 1

while True:
    try:
        batimentos = float(batimentos)
        if batimentos == 0:
            batimentos = input("Introduza um valor diferente de 0. ")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        batimentos = input("Nao inseriu um valor adequado, qual é o batimento cardiaco medio? ")

print (BatCard)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dia da Semana': (semana), 
                   'Glicemia': (NivGlicemia), 
                   'Batimento cardiaco medio': (BatCard)})

print(df)
```

EDIT: Original problem solved, updated code. Now getting the following error in my attempt to attributing inputs to a list: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: You need to define `NivGlicemia` before you reference it.

Comment: Before your first input loop add `NivGlicemia = []`. That creates an empty list that you can then `append` items to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NivGlicemia = ()` creates a tuple because you are using parenthesis. And you can't change a tuple, thus a tuple has no method `append`.

To create a list you must use square brackets:

```
NivGlicemia = []
```